# Reading a database diagram

Tags: mysql, database, diagram

I've been trying to figure out how to get the products that match a certain category id but I have been unable to figure out how to move from category to products.

How would a query that basically selects all products that match a certain category id look?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT products.*
FROM products,
     product_category
WHERE product_category.categoryid = CATEGORY_ID
  AND products.catalogid = product_category.catalogid
```

Or if you prefer a join:

```
SELECT products.*
FROM products
INNER JOIN product_category ON products.catalogid = product_category.catalogid
WHERE product_category.categoryid = CATEGORY_ID
```

Simply replace `CATEGORY_ID` by the ID of the category you wish to select.

`product_category` is a link table, joining the tables `products` and `product_category` together: it contains the `catalogid`, referencing the ID of the category, and `catalogid`, referencing the ID of the product.